# OOP JavaScript + Three.js: OrbitControls not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm playing a bit around with [`THREE.js`](http://threejs.org) and Object-oriented JavaScript.

Code: https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/581492be11db361c39ee

My browser displays the correct output, but OrbitControls don't seem to work. Any clue how I can make this work? Spitting up OrbitControls in a function (non-prototype) won't be a solution since I don't pass the variables outside the model.

Comment: `line 75`, does OrbitControls is a browser that has `document` and `window`?

Comment: @fuyushimoya It's an web app, this is the call to check wether it's loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're having comes from only 1 frame being displayed. 
You need to make your render loop recursive. You have

```
requestAnimationFrame(ixmodel.render);
```

commented out. This is what will allow your updates to be shown. Uncomment that and it should work.

Comment: I commented it out because it gives me a ``[Error] TypeError: Argument 1 ('callback') to DOMWindow.requestAnimationFrame must be a function
 requestAnimationFrame (app.js, line 70)
 render (app.js, line 70)
 (anonymous function) (app.js, line 84)`` error

Comment: Define your ixmodel outside of the if statement. (Wait to give it a value until it reaches the setTimeout). Replace this.callback with ixmodel.render(); If you still get errors, it may be because you put "use strict".

Comment: Thanks, but getting this error now: ``[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ixmodel.render')
 render (app.js, line 70)
 (anonymous function) (app.js, line 85)``. I updated the codebase to match your comment: https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/581492be11db361c39ee

Comment: You still override the ixmodel you declared outside the if statement. Remove the 'var' keyword from ixmodel inside your statement. Oh, and no parenthesis on the ixmodel.render inside the requestAnimationFrame();

Comment: Of course! Thanks man. Now I'm getting a ``Maximum call stack size exceeded`` error... Looking into it

Comment: You have requestAnimationFrame(ixmodel.render()). It needs to be requestAnimationFrame(ixmodel.render);

Comment: Aah, added the () because I'm getting an infinite loop with ``[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.renderer.render')
 render (app.js, line 70)`` without

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81874/discussion-between-james-mcdowell-and-bob-wassermann).