# THREE.js not drawing class objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, render, scene

When my code runs, I don't see anything drawn on the scene. There are no errors, but I don't see the three ArrowHelper members drawn.

However, if I create 3 local ArrowHelper variables in my draw() function and add those to the scene, it works.

The ArrowHelper's are drawn each time render is called with the above code. The reason I don't want to use that version is because I think it is adding new meshes to the scene at each render call. I would prefer to only add one mesh and then change it.

I have a common function for Frame that returns a new instance of Frame. I use that common function to instantiate the variable A.

Can anyone explain what's going wrong with my first method? (Any other info, advice, etc. is welcome)

My source code is:

main.js:

```
var init=false;
var scene, camera, controls, renderer;

var A;


function initScene()
{

  // Create scene and camera
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
  camera.position.z = 5;

  // Create Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  // Create controls object for mouse control of the scene
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );


  A = Frame.common.unit();
  A.draw();

  // Set init flag
  init = true;

  // Call render
  render();
}



function render() 
{
  if(!init)
  {
    console.log("Calling initScene");
    initScene();
  }

  // Request frame and call controls.update()
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  controls.update(); 

  // Render
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

frame.js:

```
var Frame = function(p, i, j, k) 
{
  console.log("Frame instance created");
  this.p = p;
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.k = k;

  this.i_arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( this.i, this.p, 1, 0x0000ff );
  this.j_arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( this.j, this.p, 1, 0x00ff00 );
  this.k_arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( this.k, this.p, 1, 0xff0000 );
};

Frame.common = 
{
  unit: function()
  {
    console.log("\"Unit\" Frame instance being created");
    var p = new vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 0);
    var i = new vec3.fromValues(1, 0, 0);
    var j = new vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0);
    var k = new vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 1);
    var result = new Frame(p, i, j, k,);

    return result;
  },

  rand: function()
  {
    console.log("Random Frame instance being created");
    var p = {};
    vec3.random(p);

    var i_hat = {};
    vec3.random(i_hat);

    var j_hat = {};
    vec3.random(j_hat);

    var k_hat = {};
    vec3.random(k_hat);

    var result = new Frame(p, i_hat, j_hat, k_hat);
    return result;
  }

} // End common

Frame.prototype.draw = function(scene)
{
  scene.add(this.i_arrow, this.j_arrow, this.k_arrow);

  /*var i = new THREE.Vector3(this.i[0], this.i[1], this.i[2]);
  var j = new THREE.Vector3(this.j[0], this.j[1], this.j[2]);
  var k = new THREE.Vector3(this.k[0], this.k[1], this.k[2]);

  var p = new THREE.Vector3(this.p[0], this.p[1], this.p[2]);

  var i_arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( i, p, 1, 0x0000ff );
  var j_arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( j, p, 1, 0x00ff00 );
  var k_arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( k, p, 1, 0xff0000 );
    scene.add(i_arrow);
    scene.add(j_arrow);
    scene.add(k_arrow);*/
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>HTM Tutorial</title>
    <style>
      body {margin: 0;}
      canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload='initScene()'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/three/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/gl-matrix/dist/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/frame.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you instantiate the variable `A`?

Comment: Why did you add A.draw(scene); in render? Cant you add ArrowHelpers in initScene. Render method is in animation loop, so every time it's repeating A.draw(scene) method.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah I should put that in the initScene function. I'm used to redrawing things in OpenGL at each render function call. I changed that, but I still do not see the ArrowHelpers in the scene.

Comment: @gaitat I edited my question to show how I instantiate A

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116058/oop-javascript-three-javascript-orbitcontrols-not-working

Comment: @gaitat I'm not sure that we have the same question though. That question is about having all the rendering code in a class. I just want to add class members to a scene so that I can define various draw() methods for different objects.

Comment: not the question. look at the gist.

Comment: @gaitat Sorry, but I don't understand what is significant about the gist. It seems like they're doing things roughly the same as me, but all contained in a class.

Comment: @gaitat Can you shed some light on what I should be getting from the gist? I would greatly appreciate it. Are you able to re-produce my problem?

Comment: can you put all your code somewhere?

Comment: @gaitat Yes, thank you for taking the time to look at it. I edited the question to include all of the code.

Comment: `var result = new Frame(p, i, j, k,);` extra comma after k. Added to fiddle your code, a bit changed render and animate methods. Check it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFkMy/45/). Init method is a bit different, just update with your code.

Comment: @uhura Thanks for the fiddle code. I ran that and it does work, but with "too many errors to report in console." I tried to use your init and animate functions and move the Frame code over to frame.js...I get the same console messages, but I don't see anything drawn. I like the OOP model, but I think I will just try to find another way to do this. Thanks for all the help.